# Calling Javascript function from if statment in HTML

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

This code is wriiten in VS 2003 -asp.net

in the HTML page, I have a javascript function **checkuser()** defined which returns boolean.
I would like to enclose the following in a call to this function

`<A onclick="stageClear(); stageEditor();" href="javascript: void(0);">Add new Stage</A>`

I want something like

`<%if checkuser() then%>
 <A onclick="stageClear(); stageEditor();" href="javascript: void(0);">Add new Stage</A>
<% end if %>`

**But I am getting the error checkuser() not defined**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks as if it is looking for an asp function called checkuser.

if you wanted to do it with js you would need to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (checkuser()) {
      document.write('<a onclick="stageClear(); stageEditor();" href="javascript: void(0);">Add new Stage</a>');
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to call the `checkuser()` function inside a server-side code block (as the one you show), you must define the function on the page's code behind, not on the client-side using JavaScript.

In other words, you need to have a function called

```
protected bool checkuser()
{
    return true;//just an example
}
```

And then you can call it as you intended to.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix your back end and your front end code.

```
<a onclick="clickHandler()" href="javascript:void(0)">Stuff</a>
```

and the JS:

```
<script>
    function clickHandler(){
        if(checkuser()){
            //do something
        }else{
            //do something else
        }
    }
</script>
```